# Measuring elapsed time in QML

Tags: qt, time, qml, qtquick2, qt-quick

Let's consider the following example: we have a Qt Quick Controls `Button`. The user clicks it twice within 5 seconds. After pushing the `Button` for the first time, the QML `Timer` is running for these 5 seconds. We want to measure the time elapsed between two clicks, with a millisecond accuracy.

Unfortunately, the QML `Timer` can't show us the elapsed time.

As suggested on the BlackBerry forums, it would be possible to compare the dates. This isn't very handy, though, since the first click might occur on `31 Dec 2015, 23:59:55` and the second on `1 Jan 2016, 00:00:05` and the check would have to be complex.

Is there any better  option?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As explained in the comments, QML `Timer` is not suitable for your specific needs since it is synchronized with the animation timer (further details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22754926/2538363)) and thus its resolution is dependent on animation timer as well.

@qCring solution is for sure satisfying and I would prefer such an approach, if an higher precision is needed or a better performance (see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21066057/2538363) and the interesting link at the bottom about improving precision).

However, given your requirements, a *pure* QML/JS approach is perfectly feasible. In this case you can exploit JavaScript `Date`, both because it's [easy to calculate elapsed time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14297656/2538363), using [`getTime()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettime.asp), but also because QML fully supports JS `Date` and also [extends](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-date.html) it with some useful functions.

Here is a simple example:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3

ApplicationWindow {
    width: 300
    height: 300
    visible: true

    property double startTime: 0

    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent

        Text {
            id: time
            font.pixelSize: 30
            text: "--"
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignCenter
        }

        Button {
            text: "Click me!"
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignCenter

            onClicked: {
                if(startTime == 0){
                    time.text = "click again..."
                    startTime = new Date().getTime()
                } else {
                    time.text = new Date().getTime() - startTime + " ms"
                    startTime = 0
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You don't mention in your question if the measured time is only for debugging purposes or if it will be needed for other calculations. Because if not QML offers a [very simple way](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-debugging.html#timer) to debug the time spent doing various operations using `console.time("id string")` and `console.timeEnd("id string")`.

An example using a `Button` would look like this:

```
Button {
    text: "click here"
    property bool measuring: false
    onClicked: {
        if(!measuring){
            console.time("button")
            measuring=true
        } else {
            console.timeEnd("button")
            measuring=false
        }
    }
}
```

This will print the time in ms to the console, and can be very useful to measure the time needed to execute some long operations in QML.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, the QML `Timer` doesn't provide a property to check the elapsed time. But you could write your custom Timer in C++ and expose it to QML:

## MyTimer.h

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QElapsedTimer>

class MyTimer : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(int elapsed MEMBER m_elapsed NOTIFY elapsedChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(bool running MEMBER m_running NOTIFY runningChanged)
private:
    QElapsedTimer m_timer;
    int m_elapsed;
    bool m_running;
public slots:
    void start() {
        this->m_elapsed = 0;
        this->m_running = true;

        m_timer.start();
        emit runningChanged();
    }

    void stop() {
        this->m_elapsed = m_timer.elapsed();
        this->m_running = false;

        emit elapsedChanged();
        emit runningChanged();
    }

signals:
    void runningChanged();
    void elapsedChanged();
};
```

After registering via `qmlRegisterType<MyTimer>("MyStuff", 1, 0, "MyTimer")` it's available in QML:

## Window.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import MyStuff 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    width: 800
    height: 600
    visible: true

    Button {
        id: button
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: timer.running ? "stop" : "start"
        checkable: true

        onClicked: {
            if (timer.running) {
                timer.stop()
                label.text = timer.elapsed + "ms"
            } else { 
                timer.start()
            }
        }

        MyTimer {
            id: timer
        }
    }

    Text {
        id: label
        anchors.left: button.right
        anchors.verticalCenter: button.verticalCenter
        text: "0ms"
        visible: !timer.running
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!